# Mysql join query help, not working as required

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get all table records from table_1 and Username from table_2 by joining with userID from table_1

"UserID save in table_1, column name msg_from"

Below query fetching only one record by user. Please help me to get all messages.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.subject, t1.msg_from, t1.msg_date, t1.msg_status, t2.username
FROM table_1 AS t1, table_2 AS t2
WHERE t2.id = t1.msg_from
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is not working as required? The query looks about okay to me.

Comment: This question is missing: table information of both? tables. It misses an accurate description of what happens currently, and an accurate description of what you expect to happen. It can help to set up a quick example on sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  t1.subject, 
  t1.msg_from, 
  t1.msg_date, 
  t1.msg_status, 
  t2.username 
FROM table_1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN  table_2 AS t2 
  ON t2.id = t1.msg_from
```

If u have column name with `UserID` then you can put `t2.UserID = t1.msg_from` at the last of the Query.

Comment: I already fixed, But thank you very much :) i accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish that with a LEFT JOIN similar to this:

```
"SELECT t1.id, t1.subject, t1.msg_from, t1.msg_date, t1.msg_status, t2.username 
 FROM table_1 AS t1 
 LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON t1.msg_from = t2.UserID"
```

Wasn't sure from what you posted what the field name for the user id on t2 was so I use "t2.UserID", but you can easily swap it out for the real field name.  If you end up with duplicate records you can add a GROUP BY.